# jQuery : Placing object in center of page

Tags: jquery

I want to center the Obj "wrapper" in the center of the page (What means vertically)
jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
win_height = $(window).height();
doc_height = $('#wrapper').height();
$('#wrapper').css({'margin-top':(win_height/2)-(doc_height/2)});
});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:100px;height:400px;margin: 0 auto;">

</div>
```

Its not working, Whats wrong ?
Thanks !

Comment: Please edit your post to include the verbiage "vertical alignment"  because I got some haters down voting a correct answer for center alignment.

Comment: Your code is working fine, just add `margin: auto;` to get horizontal centring: http://jsfiddle.net/Fkw42/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in css it would be something like

```
#wrapper{
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -200px; //half of height
   height: 400px;
}
```

in jq it would work with: (maybe some little logical mistake, because of bit tired)

```
var objHeight = $("#wrapper").height() /2;
var winHeight = $(window).height() /2;
$('#wrapper').css("top", (winHeight - objHeight) + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Like this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    center_y = (jQuery(window).height() - $('#wrapper').height() ) / 2;
    center_x = (jQuery(window).width() - $('#wrapper').width() ) / 2;
    $('#wrapper').css({'margin-top':center_y ,'margin-left':center_x  });
});
```

Or you can use CSS :-

```
#wrapper{margin: 0 auto;}
```

this will make it center on X Line

Thanks,